# Is there "Evaluate Expression" functionality in Visual Studio 2012, similar to the option in Android Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, android-studio

In Android studio, I can, while debugging and after a breakpoint has been hit, evaluate code based on the variables and state once that breakpoint has been hit.

Is there similar functionality within Visual Studio 2012? I haven't been able to find any reference to it, but I'm not sure what other names it could go by, if any. I'm using C#, if it makes any difference.

For more information on the feature in Android Studio, [this link](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-debug.html#breakPointsDebug) explains it quite well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Immediate Window to evalute almost any C# expression.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for, perfect!